How to fix "Unrecognized character" error in clearmake when using file names with spaces?
I have a Makefile created with cmake version 2.8.12.
When starting the build with "make" it works as intended. But when I try the same build with "clearmake" it failes like this:
clearmake_7317_host_name: Error: File "labview/CMakeFiles/LabVIEW.dir/build.make", line 134
clearmake_7317_host_name: Error: Unrecognized character "\"

When we look into the "labview/CMakeFiles/LabVIEW.dir/build.make" file on line 134:
labview/application_name: ../labview/support/Message\ Queue/Enqueue\ Message.vi
As you can see the problem lies within the spaces in file names.
My question would be, how do I solve this issue, without having to rename the files.
Are there any clearmake configurations, which could help overcoming this?
I already tried to put the paths with spaces in quotes like " ... " but it didn't help. It even raised a new error like the on before but with "
clearmake_7317_host_name: Error: Unrecognized character """

clearmake Version:
clearmake -ver
clearmake                         9.1.0.7 (Wed May 29 20:22:49 2024) 64-bit


clearmake, even in GNU Make emulation mode, is not an exact duplicate.  Probably you'll need to contact ClearCase support for advice with this.  It's been a long time since I used clearmake but my suspicion is the answer will be, you're out of luck.  In general make doesn't really support filenames containing whitespace; some very simple things will work but many other things won't.  If at all possible it's best to rename the files and avoid the hassle.

^^ Also, CMake generates build systems targeting a particular toolset.  When using its makefile generator, you should expect that the result is intended for standard UNIX make, not for alternatives such as clearmake.

You can run a script removing the escaping of spaces. You have to do so after every CMake run.
